# getting a pojo from a mongo doc using morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Please can someone explain me this code using to create a pojo from a mongo doc?  Is it necessary to create a class which contain database fields+getters and setters?

> Morphia morphia=....;
>       MongoClient  mongoClient = ............;
>       DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "contact" );
>       String contactId=.....;
>       //load the object from the collection
>       BasicDBObject idObj=new BasicDBObject ("_id", new ObjectId(contactId));
>       BasicDBObject  obj=(BasicDBObject db.getCollection("personnal").findOne(idObj);
>       Contact contacy=morphia.fromDBObject(Contact.class,obj);

What value must be afect to contactId?

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using Morphia's API if you have it available?

`datastore.get(Contact.class, new ObjectId(contactId));`